# Ant Property echo is not working

Tags: ant

I have the ant task updating the ant property in `build.properties`.

## ant task:

```
<for list="${jar.list}" param="jar">
<sequential>
<loadproperties srcfile="${basedir}/build.properties"/> 
<if>
<isset property="@{application}.cp"/>
<then>
<propertyfile file="${basedir}/build.properties">   
<entry  key="@{application}.cp" value="${path.separator}" operation="+" />
<entry  key="@{application}.cp" value="${shipment.dir}/workspace/${common.bw.jars.dirname}/@{jar}" operation="+"/>
</propertyfile>
</then>
<else>
<propertyfile file="${basedir}/build.properties">   
<entry  key="@{application}.cp" value="${shipment.dir}/workspace/${common.bw.jars.dirname}/@{jar}" operation="+"/>
</propertyfile>
</else>
</if>                                                   
</sequential>
</for>      
<loadproperties srcfile="${basedir}/build.properties"/> 
<echo>  ${@{application}.cp} </echo>
```

The build.properties is updating with out any problem, but when I read the properties updated by above ant task, I get only the first value set by ant task.

eg: ant task is creating properties as below

## build.properties:

```
application.libs=/app/twix16/Jenkins/Buildframework/workspace/built_libraries/BP.Marko.Shared_v1.0.projlib\:/app/twix16/Jenkins/Buildframework/workspace/built_libraries/BWUnit.projlib
application.cp=/app/twix16/Jenkins/Buildframework/workspace/jars/SelectDocId.jar\:/app/twix16/Jenkins/Buildframework/workspace/jars/TextDiff.jar
```

But   ${@{application}.cp}  is printing only /app/twix16/Jenkins/Buildframework/workspace/jars/SelectDocId.jar

any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Properties in Ant are immutable, see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html

```
"whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables."
```